# Not able to add hidden-sm hidden-xs bootstrap classes to a row splitter

Tags: sxa

I am able to import the package by adding custom classes in the section "add-your-classes-here". But, when I try to add the bootstrap classes like "hidden-sm", "hidden-xs", they are not actually getting added to div tags.

Comment: are you adding as "add-your-classes-here hidden-sm" ??? or have you removed the tag `add-your-classes-here` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding class after exporting markup from Creative Exchange. You can utilize the advanced options for the grid.

[image]

You can also create you own CSS classes from here

[image]

You can learn more here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/structure/change_the_layout_of_a_rendering